# AppSettings: Количество пар ключ-значение

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, проблема такова. Создаю файл XML App.config в папке приложения следующего содержания

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>    
        <add key="1" value="2" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Затем в программе хочу посмотреть кол-во пар (ключ/значение):

```
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count)
```

Выводит 0 почему-то, а не 1. Пробовал больше пар создать, все равно 0 выдается.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сделал тоже самое - выводит корректное количество.

Comment: И обратиться тоже можете к ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["1"] без всяких эксепшенов ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, не знаю в чем была проблема, опять заново добавил автоматом App.config, но уже через Visual Studio напрямую, а не через проводник, вручную создавая файл. Наверное, все дело было в этом.

Comment: Да, я добавлял именно при помощьи студии. Возможно при таком подходе студия прописывает где-то о существовании подобного конфига для приложения и следовательно менеджер и все  остальные видят его.